# Парсинг html - таблицы через jsoup библиотеку

Tags: android, jsoup

Всем привет! 
Помогите разобраться:
Нужно распарсить таблицу с сайта, и вывести её в приложении
Где у меня здесь ошибка?
Я очень новичок

```
        gridvw = findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        new NewContent().execute();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    public class NewContent extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc =  Jsoup.connect("url").get();
                // content = doc.select(".th_header");
                table  = doc.select(".table-responsive").first();
                // разбиваем строки по тегу
                idx     =  table.select("th");
               // titleContent.clear();
                for (int i =0; i < idx.size(); i++){
                    Element row = idx.get(i); // строки
                    Elements cols = row.select("td"); // столбцы
                    for (Element e: cols) {
                        list.add(e.text().toString());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result) {
           gridvw.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вроде бы ошибок нет. Что именно у  вас не работает? Ошибку выдаёт, падает, не отображает список или он неправильный или данные с сайта не удалось получить?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что здесь ошибка?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добрый вечер! Мне нужно, чтобы данные вывелись в таблицу. Но у меня они выпадают просто в список, хотя я использую GridView. Я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы он в таблицу их сливал

Comment: @0xdb код работает с GridView как со списком. А мне надо как с таблицей

Comment: Ну, по идее вам надо как-то указать кол-во колонок. Например так: `android:numColumns="2"`, добавив это в атрибуты для GridView в разметке.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо огромное! Получилось:) Форматировать колонки и чтобы можно было скроллить в стороны это в стилях GridView можно настроить? У меня 9 колонок и все они влезли в экран смартфона :) буквы по столбику получились

Comment: @Alena.Shabanova, насколько мне известно нет простого (а может даже и сложного) способа скролить таблицы во все стороны. Как именно вам нужно отображать колонки я не знаю, засим не могу ничего посоветовать. Возможно вам стоит остановиться просто на двух.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант если нужно широкую таблицу ее можно сделать в HTML и засунуть в WebView
У меня так в одном приложении сделана таблица размеров, где одна часть всегда статична (название мерки) и вторая (значение мерки) скролится вправо-влево вверх-вниз